# A pyparsing question for isinstance for list

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I am new to the **pyparsing** module and find it such a nice tool for parsing. However, when I try to test the resulting lists with the isinstance function for a list, it doesn't seem to work for me when using Python 3.7.

The following 2 programs with their output hopefully encapsulate the issue that I am having.

Program with pyparsing...

```
import pyparsing as pp

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Testing isinstance with pyparsing...")

    greet = pp.Word(pp.alphas) + "," + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + "!"

    for greeting_str in ["Hello, World!","Bonjour, Monde!","Hola, Mundo!","Hallo, Welt!",]:
        greeting = greet.parseString(greeting_str)
        print("Parsed greeting: ", greeting)
        res = isinstance(greeting, list)
        print("Is this a list? -> ", res)
```

with resulting output...

```
Testing isinstance with pyparsing...
Parsed greeting:  ['Hello', ',', 'World', '!']
Is this a list? ->  False
Parsed greeting:  ['Bonjour', ',', 'Monde', '!']
Is this a list? ->  False
Parsed greeting:  ['Hola', ',', 'Mundo', '!']
Is this a list? ->  False
Parsed greeting:  ['Hallo', ',', 'Welt', '!']
Is this a list? ->  False
```

Program without pyparsing import...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Testing isinstance without pyparsing...")

    parsed_greetings = [['Hello', ',', 'World', '!'], ['Bonjour', ',', 'Monde', '!'], ['Hola', ',', 'Mundo', '!'], ['Hallo', ',', 'Welt', '!']]

    for parsed_greeting in parsed_greetings:
        print("Parsed greeting: ", parsed_greeting)
        res = isinstance(parsed_greeting, list)
        print("Is this a list? -> ", res)
```

with the resulting output...

```
Testing isinstance without pyparsing...
Parsed greeting:  ['Hello', ',', 'World', '!']
Is this a list? ->  True
Parsed greeting:  ['Bonjour', ',', 'Monde', '!']
Is this a list? ->  True
Parsed greeting:  ['Hola', ',', 'Mundo', '!']
Is this a list? ->  True
Parsed greeting:  ['Hallo', ',', 'Welt', '!']
Is this a list? ->  True
```

In summary, the **isinstance** function for testing a list seems to be working as expected when not using pyparsing, but when I use pyparsing it doesn't seem to work correctly. I looked through the pyparsing documentation but could not find any mention of this issue or a possibility of using **list** as a variable name.

Using the **isinstance** function for testing a list is very helpful in some of my later processing, so any insight into this is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to pyparsing! Before your `isinstance` line, insert `print(type(greeting))`. You'll find that pyparsing returns a rich object of type `ParseResults`, which has features in common with both lists and dicts, depending on how your grammar builds it. The string representation of a ParseResults looks like a list, since this is how it is most often used, and it can be accessed just like a list. Try `print(greeting[0])`. You should get 'Hello', 'Bonjour', etc. You can find more information on pyparsing in the [online documentation](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/pyparsing_2.4.7/).

Comment: Ouch - that version of the docs says this "Process the parsed results, returned as a list of strings."  The [latest version](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#steps-to-follow) is more correct: "Process the parsed results, returned as a ParseResults object. The ParseResults object can be accessed as if it were a list of strings. Matching results may also be accessed as named attributes of the returned results, if names are defined in the definition of the token pattern, using setResultsName()." Sorry for the confusion!